# Match query with multiple words matching in the field

Tags: elasticsearch, match

How to apply match query on the field which has multiple keywords matching like "los angeles" has two words in it. How to match it from the below data structure

```
  "addresses" : [
        {
          "type" : "Home",
          "address" : "Los Angeles,CA,US"
        }
      ]
```

Below are my mappings and settings, created custom settings and filters

```
 PUT /test
 {
   "settings": {
     "analysis": {
       "filter" : {
             "my_word_delimiter" : {
                 "type" : "word_delimiter",
                 "type_table": [
                   "# => ALPHANUM",
                   "+ => ALPHANUM",
                   "@ => ALPHANUM",
                          "% => ALPHANUM",
                          "~ => ALPHANUM",
                          "^ => ALPHANUM",
                          "$ => ALPHANUM",
                          "& => ALPHANUM",
                          "' => ALPHANUM",
                          "\" => ALPHANUM",
                          "\/ => ALPHANUM",
                          ", => ALPHANUM"
                 ],
                 "preserve_original": "true",
                 "generate_word_parts":false,
                 "generate_number_parts":false,
                 "split_on_case_change":false,
                 "split_on_numerics":false,
                 "stem_english_possessive":false
             }   
         },
       "analyzer": {
             "default": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                "filter": [
                   "lowercase",
                   "my_word_delimiter"
                ]
             }
          },
       "normalizer": {
         "keyword_lowercase": {
           "type": "custom",
           "filter": [
             "lowercase"
           ]
         }
       }
     }
   },
   "mappings": {
     "dynamic": "strict",
     "properties": {
      "addresses": {
         "type": "nested",
         "properties": {
           "address": {
             "type": "text"
           },
           "type": {
             "type": "keyword"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

tried with the below query but not getting the results

```
 {
   "from": "0",
   "size": "30",
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "must": [
         {
           "bool": {
             "should": [
               {
                 "nested": {
                   "path": "addresses",
                   "query": {
                     "match": {
                       "addresses.address": {
                         "query": "Los Angeles",
                         "operator": "and"
                       }
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
             ]
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   },
   "sort": [
     {
       "_score": {
         "order": "desc"
       }
     }
   ]
 }
```

Is there any problem with the settings created

Comment: the above search query returns the document. Can you please explain your use case more clearly? Do you want that `match` query should return only `"los angeles"` ?

Comment: Edited the query, I tried with "los angeles"

Comment: still your search query is returning the document. Can you please share your expected search result also and would be great if you can explain your requirement more clearly?

Comment: yeah it's working My data doesn't contain "los angeles", there is a problem with the data dump

Comment: @Bhavya Not getting results in case address has value like "Los Angeles,CA,US". If there is a space after angeles then getting that record Ex: "Los Angeles ,CA,US". Is there any problem settings ? Added the settings in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are not getting results in case the address has value like `"Los Angeles,CA,US"`, because you are using `whitespace` tokenizer.**

> The whitespace tokenizer breaks text into terms whenever it encounters
> a whitespace character.

Since you are using `and` operator with `match` query, so the query should retrieve that data which have both `Los` and `Angeles`, but due to whitespace tokenizer, no token for `Angeles` is generated, therefore no results are returned.

```
 POST/_analyze
    {
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "text": "Los Angeles,CA,US"
    }
```

The tokens are:

```
    {
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "Los",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "Angeles,CA,US",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 17,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

But in the case of `"Los Angeles ,CA,US"`, since there is a whitespace after `Angeles`, so the tokens generated are: `Los`, `Angeles`, `,CA,US`

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

Keep the mapping same, apart from changing from `whitespace` to`"tokenizer":"standard"`

**Analyze API**

**The [standard tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) provides grammar-based tokenization**

```
{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "text": "Los Angeles ,CA,US"
}
```

The tokens are:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "Los",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "Angeles",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "CA",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "US",
      "start_offset": 16,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "addresses": [
    {
      "type": "Home",
      "address": "Los Angeles,CA,US"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Using the same search query as given in the result**

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64624353",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.26706278,
        "_source": {
          "addresses": [
            {
              "type": "Home",
              "address": "Los Angeles,CA,US"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

**NOTE: If you want to use `whitespace` tokenizer, then remove `"operator": "and"` from the search query, that you will get the required result**

**Update 1:**

Try using this updated mapping:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_word_delimiter": {
          "type": "word_delimiter",
          "type_table": [
            "# => ALPHANUM",
            "+ => ALPHANUM",
            "@ => ALPHANUM",
            "% => ALPHANUM",
            "~ => ALPHANUM",
            "^ => ALPHANUM",
            "$ => ALPHANUM",
            "& => ALPHANUM",
            "' => ALPHANUM",
            "\" => ALPHANUM",
            "\/ => ALPHANUM"
          ],
          "preserve_original": "true",
          "generate_word_parts": true,
          "generate_number_parts": false,
          "split_on_case_change": false,
          "split_on_numerics": false,
          "stem_english_possessive": false
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_word_delimiter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "normalizer": {
        "keyword_lowercase": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "addresses": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "address": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. [generate_word_parts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html#_add_to_an_analyzer) is set to `true` so that the filter includes tokens consisting of alphabetical characters in the output.
2. [Word delimiter token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html#analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter), splits tokens at non-alphanumeric characters. Have removed `", => ALPHANUM"`, from `type_table`

Comment: Even though I have used whitespace tokenizer, i have extended it with the token filter "my_word_delimiter" right? what is the purpose of "my_word_delimiter" here in this case then ?

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: why does the operator "and" is not required if I use whitespace tokenizer, I need both the words in address